# Power button shuts down despite being set to hibernate. Start > power > hibernate works

Tags: windows-10, power-management, hibernate

I have a dell M6800 running windows 10 pro. The power button is set to hibernate but it shuts down instead.

[image]

When I hit start > power > hibernate the laptop hibernates just fine so it does have the ability to do so.

Edit: It used to work but has not for so long I could not recall anything happening at the same time.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: Birdman3131, any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update to the latest driver for your display adapter?  It's possible that a previous update caused the problem originally.

Personally, I would manually [create a System Restore point](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4571-system-restore-point-create-windows-10-a.html) to have a good place to fall-back just in case, then try updating that driver.  If the problem persists, try utilizing an older version.

Comment: Why would this not effect clicking hibernate in the start menu? Because that hibernates just fine.

Comment: I hear you, but normally it is my standard Troubleshooting 101 procedure to scrutinize the video driver when faced with similar problems.  Since it has not worked *"for so long"*, it is a bit more difficult to reverse-engineer any potential changes that may be the root cause of the problem.